# Voltage divider from speaker to line level generates noise/huming

Tags: power, amplifier, audio, line, level

I have a really old device and I can only access the speaker wires of it. I want to setup a line level from the speaker so I can connect it to another device.

I used a very simple voltage divider (2 resistor like the image below) to bring down the voltage from the speaker to line level (close to 1v) - as many people suggest online. It works fine, however there is a noise/huming that bothers me when I connect this line level to another speaker (using pre amp). It's not very loud, but when there is no song playing it is very distracting.

Reading online, it appears that using cheap resistors to bring the voltage down may create lots of noise. So what do you recommend I should do? Is there any "non cheap" resistor which is "audio grade" so I can use it to make this voltage divider?

NOTE: in the old device's speaker, the sound is perfect, absolutelly no noise. So the sound coming from the speaker is clear of audible noise.

**EDIT: since you guys took your time to help me, I decided to make this question more clear and created the image below, which is exactly what I have in my situation. I didnt do any other thing. Many people report great success with a circuit similar to below, why do I have hum/hiss/noise on my output? I already tried soldering other resistor of similar values but the problem still remains. Any suggestion I can try?**

[image]

Comment: Did you connect the attenuator at one end of a shielded audio cable that feeds the preamp at the other end of the cable?

Comment: Try STP shielded pair ground only at source

Comment: Jonathan, are you planning on disconnecting the existing speaker when connecting up to the other device? Also, do you have any specifications about the speaker itself (Ohms) and/or the power driving the speaker?

Comment: Your problem is not the tiny amount of noise introduced by the resistors. Your problem is mains hum pickup. The most expensive audiophool resistors won't help you here.

Comment: @Audioguru I dont have any preamp... I just need to get the speaker level to line level so I can connect to something (like my JBL boombox). I edited my post and provided you an image of my circuit, hope it helps to clear things out.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 what is STP shielded pair? I made an edit to my post providing an image to you take a look. I am using normal copper wires, nothing fancy.

Comment: @jonk I edited my question in order to provide you with the information you requested. I want to connect the line level to something like a JBL boombox or any other input that accepts line level... but everytime I do that, there is a noise/hum/hiss... not very loud, but it is enough to bother.

Comment: @brhans but why the original speaker does not have any hum/noise if the problem is with mains/power supply... anyway, is there something I can do? The device is powered with a 10V DC jack which also provides 10V to the speaker.

Comment: Is there a noise difference when you swap the two line level wires?

Comment: What is the old device and how it drives the speaker? Is there a schematic available? If the speaker is a bridged load on a differential output, then neither wire is a ground and it cannot be connected to a ground referenced input. Old mains powered devices may have unisolated circuitry so what you are doing may be unsafe. Or, you might just be using a ground-requiring device on an ungrounded mains socket which can be more than enough of a reason to cause hum, depending on the device. It might be solved with an audio transformer or differential input.

Comment: You show two wires feeding the input of the boombox. The signal wire is an antenna that picks up hum and all kinds of interference. The two wires should be a shielded audio cable. The signal wire should connect to the wire inside the shield wire. Isn't the boombox powered from a battery so that there is no ground loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the hum is already there, and not being introduced by your solution. If that's the case then there's not much you can do, short of inserting a filter to remove it. Is it possible that you've simply been unaware of hum from the speaker? Just asking.

If your "really old device" case is earthed, then there's some chance that one side or the other of your speaker is connected to that same earth, and you should be very careful which side of your "line-level output" is considered to be ground. If you get it wrong, you might be connecting the remote amplifier's ground to your equipment's speaker output, and your remote amplifier's signal input directly to mains earth. Not only will that cause huge amounts of hum, it will cause equipment-damagingly high currents to flow where they shouldn't.

My advice is to check continuity in your old equipment, between the speaker terminals and mains earth to see if that's the case (pun intended). The good news is that the earthed side of the speaker (if this is true) will make a good ground point, which you can use as the shield around your signal line, and which will help with your problem.

In any case, you should be careful when connecting two pieces of equipment together that are connected in any way to mains earth, to avoid ground loops that can break things. If, for example, your speaker is driven from a H-Bridge amplifier, then each of its terminals voltage varies independently of the circuit ground, and if that circuit ground is connected to mains earth, then you can't safely make a direct connection from the speaker to any other piece of equipment.

I can't be sure, but that speaker is quite powerful, and the chances are good that its driver amplifier is indeed such an H-Bridge, and you should take care.

You might try using 3 resistors, as you suggested:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8dmIo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This effectively isolates both signal wires from any potential ground conflict, but the voltage across R2 is still roughly one tenth of the speaker's voltage. It might not solve your hum problem, but at least you can be sure you're not creating direct low impedance ground loops.

One thing I think is worth trying is to reduce the resistance of the divider. Given that the speaker is 4Ω, I imagine that the amplifier driving it is easily capable of handling a much heavier additional load than 3.3kΩ+330Ω. By reducing the resistor values, you decrease the impedance of your "line-level source", and you improve its ability to reject noise from other sources.

For instance, using 100Ω + 10Ω, the combined speaker and divider impedance becomes:

$$Z = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{4\Omega} + \frac{1}{100\Omega + 10\Omega}} = 3.9\Omega$$

That won't stress the amplifier much, but it provides a "line output" source  impedance of just under 10Ω, which should defeat a lot more pick-up.

The caveat is that these resistors could dissipate quite a lot of power. If R1 = 100Ω and R2 = 10Ω, and at full volume the RMS voltage across the resistors is roughly 10V and 1V respectively:

$$ P_{R1} = \frac{(10V)^2}{100\Omega} = 1W $$
$$ P_{R2} = \frac{(1V)^2}{10\Omega} = 0.1W $$

You could get away with a small \$\frac{1}{4}W\$ resistor for R2, but R1 will have to be over 1W, probably 2W to be safe.

If those resistors seem a bit too beefy, try larger resistance values, but still significantly less than 3.3kΩ + 330Ω, while keeping their ratio the same, 10:1. Like 470Ω + 47Ω, for example. Using these values, you get this power dissipation:

$$ P_{R1} = \frac{(10V)^2}{470\Omega} = 0.2W $$
$$ P_{R2} = \frac{(1V)^2}{47\Omega} = 0.02W $$

Here you could use regular \$\frac{1}{4}W\$ resistors for both R1 and R2, for an output impedance of under 47Ω; still much less than 330Ω.

Be aware though, that by reducing the impedance this way, you are also increasing the current that will flow if your are creating a ground loop between the two pieces of equipment. Consequently you are increasing the chances of breaking something.

Answer (score 2):

You need a Common mode choke or small-signal 1:1 transformer to eliminate common mode hum, the nyou can attenuate.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff8NGf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Otherwise a **better solution** is a differential Amplifier with STP wire (shielded twisted pair) shld gnd'd only at source.

[image]

With 0.1% resistor arrays get 60 dB  CMRR rejection of hum.

Comment: I edited the question with a picture so you understand better what I have. Unfortunatelly I dont have a transformer as you said... also you circuit uses 3 resistors, mine uses only 2... do you think using 3 resistor could solve my problem? I added my resistor values to the question to clear this out. About the "differential Amplifier with STP " it sounds expensive... at least here in brazil, it will probably be very expensive.

Comment: not expensive but takes more skill than 2 resistors with hum.  You have ground noise. (STP= Shielded Twisted Pair) like ethernet,

Comment: @Jonathan Worth noting that you can buy ready-made audio isolation transformers with headphone jacks inexpensively online (although I cannot vouch for their signal quality, would not be surprised if some of the very cheap ones have weaker bass).

Answer (score 0):

Lack of shielding could be the cause of noise / hum.

Here's another way.

[image]

The old device with, its speaker disconnected, is protected from damage by the 8.25 Ω - 8 W dummy load.

The voltage across the dummy load would be 3.3 V, with 4.9 W being fed to it by the old device at full volume. That would need to be reduced to much less than 1 V by turning down the volume considerably.

The reduced voltage is fed to the amplifier using single core shielded wire.